# How would I pass a json object from a ActionMethod as a parameter to a different Action Method in MVC?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

In My project i have two ActionResult Methods in my Controller. The first ActionResult method is retrieving a Json from an Ajax call.

ActionResult Method1 is something like this:....

```
public ActionResult VehicleModel(int id)
{
    var vehicle = myService.VehicleModel(id);
    myserviceService.Close();
    return Json(new { model = vehicle }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

ActionResult Method2

```
public ActionResult Vehicles(string id,  string vehicle)
{
    var _cat = _catalogue.Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.manufacturerId == id && x.Vehicle == vehicle);
    ViewData["id"] = id;
    return PartialView("_vehicle", _cat);
}
```

Now .. I would i gain access to Method 1 in method 2? What i would to do is get the json returned in method (vehicle) and pass as a parameter in Method2.. I am not so sure on how i would go about in achieving this.. Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understand you correctly.

If you want `VehicleModel` to send the data to `Vehicles` and continue from there, you should use this:

```
var jsonVehicle = Json(vehicle); //or whatever way you want to serialize your object to json
return RedirectToAction("Vehicles", new { id = this.id, vehicle = jsonVehicle});
```

This will redirect your action to `Vehicles` and will also bind the routing values.

For more information on RedirectToAction, [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).